# bandwidth-efficient listing of remote zip/jar files using Java

Tags: java, maven, zip

I sometimes have the need to search for files (not classes, rather resources) on maven central. However, the maven central search functionality is not very versatile, ie. not versatile enough for me. Is there an efficient way to retrieve the directory listings of zip/jar files using Java? Are there some Java ZIP implementations that work efficiently over networks (http/https) and do not retrieve the entire file just to get the index part? Or can I manually work around by implementing some simple retrieval algorithm that simply skips the contents and then work with that pruned local copy?

**Update**

I had a look at the Zip file specification (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)). Because there is an arbitrary comment at the end of a zip file, there is no way to reliably detect the start of central directory. The entire zip file structure is built to be sequentially read from the start of the zip file.

Comment: The directory listing of the JAR is at the end of the file. You could try downloading just the end of the file and then decoding the contents. Most likley you are better off using one of the many search engine available for what you need.

Comment: I think "_do not retrieve the entire file just to get the index part_" is not going to work without an appropriate process on the (http or whatever) server.